# PHP unix time conversion

Tags: php

I want to convert `12/31/2099` to Unix time using PHP. I tried `strtotime('12/31/2099')` but the function returns `null`.

I tried converting it to Unix time using an online conversion tool which gives `4102358400` which, when turned into a date gives `01/18/2038`.

How can I convert dates to Unix time and again convert it back to a readable format like `12/31/2099`?

Comment: as an additional question, what would the number be for 12/31/2099?

Answer (score 2):

In old versions of PHP ( < 5.1.0), strtotime supported a max date of Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. To bypass this limitation, upgrade to 5.1.0 or later.

64-bit versions are unaffected by this limitation.

For more information, see the Notes: at http://www.php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 1):

32-bit Unix timestamps run out in 2038, so if you're on a 32-bit system, that would cause a problem.

Comment: @Rocket I appreciate the reference.

Answer (score 1):

The unix timestamp of a point in time is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC to this point in time. On 2038-01-18 this will overflow a 32bit signed int - call it the Y2K bug of the unices.

Mind though, that this is a problem of the implementation, not the algotithm: Most current implementations use  an unsigned 32bit int, but it is to be expected that 32bit ints will be a thing of the past some time before 2038

Usual workarounds include an if-branch to detect whether a date is after the wraparound and adjust accordingly.

Comment: What would be last date or time for 32 bit system?

Comment: @RahulSingh: 03:14:07 UTC on Tuesday, 19 January 2038 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)